# Why Does MySQL not use an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Our MySQL(Percona Server) database have a big table cotains 10 millions rows, there are many slow query longger than 40 seconds like this:

```
  SELECT col1, Seller, col3, col4, Id, col5  
    FROM table1 
   WHERE Seller = 346761 
     AND col1 IN (2, 3, 4) 
     AND col3 = 1  
     AND col4 NOT IN (5,6,7)  
ORDER BY Id DESC 
   LIMIT 0, 20;
```

I had create index on `Seller`, and `col1`, `col3`, `col4`. These indexes are individual, not Multiple-Column Index (AKA covering index). And the `Id` is primary key.

EXPLAIN show that MySQL query this sql using Primary key as index, not index about Seller.

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trans_audit_list | index | Seller,AuditStatus | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 1483 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

When I `force index (Seller)`, it's very fast, 0.7 second.

And I found if not use limit statement, this query will use `Seller` index, will be very fast.
Why MySQL not using index on `Seller` with limit statement?

Comment: You should run EXPLAIN on the query and post the results.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have post EXPLAIN result in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple possible indices situations added to an `ORDER BY DESC` + `LIMIT` clauses [is a common problematic situation for mysql](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/)'s optimizer and one of the very little cases when forcing an index could actually be legitimate.

Please note also that your clause `IN (...)` is an additional hassle for the optimizer.

If you don't really need it I suggest to order by id `ASC` instead of `DESC` so the engine could use the benefits of the primary key ordering, which is `ASC` until further implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As you've encountered, having an index does not mean it will be used.  That goes for every database -- index selection is up to the query optimizer.  As you've tried, forcing an index does not mean you'll get the fastest result.

Following that, query caching might not be helping you -- the query plan could be cached so the index isn't even considered.

MySQL only uses one index per statement, so a covering index (multi-column) would be a good idea but you'll have to test it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-cluster index on [Seller] could have too much fragmentation, and your statistics could be out of date, then the query optimizer may not select best query plan. Check fragmentation, update statistics, or re-build your non-cluster index on Seller, certainly if you can also create covering index just for this query, if this query is frequently used by user, and it worth the cost. When you create covering index, make sure the order is what end users mostly used. Like in your query, the covering index should be on [seller->col1->col3->col4]